# Page is responsive only when resize but not in mobile/tablets - materializecss

Tags: css, materialize, responsive

I built a website using materializecss framework for responsive website. I made it responsive with columns (.m4.s12) etc but what I found out is that my website is responsive only on resize.

If I load it on my devices (or simulate in desktop browser) - mobile or tablet, the website is not responsive at all.

I tried to look for some advices but couldn't find any similar issue. [This is the website](https://www.getmehired.my/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">` tag in your `<head>`? This is a good practice to ensure mobiles and tablets work as we've come to expect.